# Sort an array by the "Levenshtein Distance" with best performance in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, levenshtein-distance

So I have a random javascript array of names...

[@larry,@nicholas,@notch] etc.

They all start with the @ symbol. I'd like to sort them by the Levenshtein Distance so that the the ones at the top of the list are closest to the search term. At the moment, I have some javascript that uses jQuery's `.grep()` on it using javascript `.match()` method around the entered search term on key press:

(code edited since first publish)

```
limitArr = $.grep(imTheCallback, function(n){
    return n.match(searchy.toLowerCase())
});
modArr = limitArr.sort(levenshtein(searchy.toLowerCase(), 50))
if (modArr[0].substr(0, 1) == '@') {
    if (atRes.childred('div').length < 6) {
        modArr.forEach(function(i){
            atRes.append('<div class="oneResult">' + i + '</div>');
        });
    }
} else if (modArr[0].substr(0, 1) == '#') {
    if (tagRes.children('div').length < 6) {
        modArr.forEach(function(i){
            tagRes.append('<div class="oneResult">' + i + '</div>');
        });
    }
}

$('.oneResult:first-child').addClass('active');

$('.oneResult').click(function(){
    window.location.href = 'http://hashtag.ly/' + $(this).html();
});
```

It also has some if statements detecting if the array contains hashtags (#) or mentions (@). Ignore that. The `imTheCallback` is the array of names, either hashtags or mentions, then `modArr` is the array sorted. Then the `.atResults` and `.tagResults` elements are the elements that it appends each time in the array to, this forms a list of names based on the entered search terms.

I **also** have the Levenshtein Distance algorithm:

```
var levenshtein = function(min, split) {
    // Levenshtein Algorithm Revisited - WebReflection
    try {
        split = !("0")[0]
    } catch(i) {
        split = true
    };

    return function(a, b) {
        if (a == b)
            return 0;
        if (!a.length || !b.length)
            return b.length || a.length;
        if (split) {
            a = a.split("");
            b = b.split("")
        };
        var len1 = a.length + 1,
            len2 = b.length + 1,
            I = 0,
            i = 0,
            d = [[0]],
            c, j, J;
        while (++i < len2)
            d[0][i] = i;
        i = 0;
        while (++i < len1) {
            J = j = 0;
            c = a[I];
            d[i] = [i];
            while(++j < len2) {
                d[i][j] = min(d[I][j] + 1, d[i][J] + 1, d[I][J] + (c != b[J]));
                ++J;
            };
            ++I;
        };
        return d[len1 - 1][len2 - 1];
    }
}(Math.min, false);
```

How can I work with algorithm (or a similar one) into my current code to sort it without bad performance?

UPDATE:

So I'm now using James Westgate's Lev Dist function. Works WAYYYY fast. So performance is solved, the issue now is using it with source...

```
modArr = limitArr.sort(function(a, b){
    levDist(a, searchy)
    levDist(b, searchy)
});
```

My problem now is general understanding on using the `.sort()` method. Help is appreciated, thanks.

Thanks!

Comment: If it's an array, why are you iterating with `for..in`? That will also iterate over the `length` property (or any other non-index property of the array, if you defined such), and inherited enumerable properties (which might exist if some of your other code tries to polyfill the ES5 array methods). You can iterate arrays with the native `.forEach`, or jQuery's `$.each`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (modArr[i]` instead of `if (modArr[0]`?

Comment: How many `.atResults`, and `.tagResults` elements are there on the page? One of each? Is their number static, or are you adding new ones dynamically? If their number is static, you should cache their references, so that you don't have to query them on each key up.

Comment: To your first comment. I'm not using the forEach method, much nicer! For the second question, it didn't really matter, that if statement should've been outside the for...in statement anyway. But I've since moved to the .forEach method, it must be outside and so I'll just grab the first one. And third question, there's only one of each element on the page, and now they're cached. Thanks.

Comment: modArr = limitArr.sort(function(a,b){
    return levDist(b,searchy) - levDist(a,searchy);
});

Comment: @JamesWestgate to the rescue again. (Note: that will sort in ascending order of similarity, which might not be the order you want; to sort in _descending_ order of likeness, use `function(a,b){ return levDist(a, searchy) - levDist(b,searchy); }`.)

Comment: Yeah, and you may want to cache the result depending on the size of the array as it may do the same calculation multiple times. Just a simple associative array would do the trick.

Comment: I have also found soundex algorithms to be useful in trying to spell check / match words.

Comment: So what you could do is put the names to be searched in buckets by their length. THen you can reduce the number of terms to check against because you only need to check the buckets within the same length as the search term +- limit. In that way you can remove the limit check in my jsperf version of the algorithm.

Comment: It compiles pretty well with closure compiler, a 50% size compression with advanced optimization with one modification: `this["levenshtein"] = function(min, split) {` on the first line to avoiding it compiling down to nothing.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I wrote an inline spell checker a few years ago and implemented a Levenshtein algorithm - since it was inline and for IE8 I did quite a lot of performance optimisation.

```
var levDist = function(s, t) {
    var d = []; //2d matrix

    // Step 1
    var n = s.length;
    var m = t.length;

    if (n == 0) return m;
    if (m == 0) return n;

    //Create an array of arrays in javascript (a descending loop is quicker)
    for (var i = n; i >= 0; i--) d[i] = [];

    // Step 2
    for (var i = n; i >= 0; i--) d[i][0] = i;
    for (var j = m; j >= 0; j--) d[0][j] = j;

    // Step 3
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        var s_i = s.charAt(i - 1);

        // Step 4
        for (var j = 1; j <= m; j++) {

            //Check the jagged ld total so far
            if (i == j && d[i][j] > 4) return n;

            var t_j = t.charAt(j - 1);
            var cost = (s_i == t_j) ? 0 : 1; // Step 5

            //Calculate the minimum
            var mi = d[i - 1][j] + 1;
            var b = d[i][j - 1] + 1;
            var c = d[i - 1][j - 1] + cost;

            if (b < mi) mi = b;
            if (c < mi) mi = c;

            d[i][j] = mi; // Step 6

            //Damerau transposition
            if (i > 1 && j > 1 && s_i == t.charAt(j - 2) && s.charAt(i - 2) == t_j) {
                d[i][j] = Math.min(d[i][j], d[i - 2][j - 2] + cost);
            }
        }
    }

    // Step 7
    return d[n][m];
}
```

Comment: I haven't gone through the code, but I've done a quick test and can verify that this is significantly faster than the OP's algorithm. Nice work!

Comment: I can see a few more tweaks for performance such as === over ==

Comment: One little thing: I notice that this is the Damerau–Levenshtein distance you calculate rather than just the Levenshtein distance. If you cut out the test for transpositions, this will be closer to what the OP wants and will run even faster. :)

Comment: Fun fact, the `var` keyword serves an actual purpose and isn't a reset button.

Comment: Thank you! This is honestly the only good performance function I've seen on the web. All the others get really slow on long string, this is fantastic. Well done. *claps hands*

Comment: So now I have the distance, how would I best use this function with javascript's .sort() method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your sort will take two arguments which are two elements to compare in the list

You want to return the two lev values for the two elements vs the search term. You probably want to write a self caching function for that. 

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Any code I can look at? Examples of using sort with something like this? Thanks again.

Comment: And I posted an example of something I tried in the original question. Thx.

Comment: @JamesWestgate I threw up a JSPerf page to compare a few implementations, and yours performs brilliantly. (You could make it even faster by implementing a limit and getting rid of the Damerau transposition.)

Comment: @JordanGray could you take a look at my code in the original question and see if I'm implementing the .sort() correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Bah, I forgot to post the link to the JSPerf page: http://jsperf.com/levenshtein-distance

Comment: If you set a limit, and you take out DT, then the performance flies. 

http://jsperf.com/levenshtein-distance/2

Note: my original implementation had buckets of items sorted alphabetically, then each letter of the alphabet also had a bucket by length, in that way I could compare items only of the same length or lengths up to a limit without the check inside the algorithm.

Comment: Running tests on a few different browsers gives very interesting results. Your algorithm frequently comes out on top—especially considering the one that runs without a limit—but Firefox seems to LOOOVE Stoianovici's. Anomalously so; I expect this is due to some oddity of the JS engine rather than an intrinsic algorithmic factor.

Comment: This answer continues to get up voted which is great. Looking at it now, there are definitely ways of improving it further, specifically around memory management / recreation of the matrix variable d, and possibly those var declarations inside the loop. Javascript engines have of course moved on since I wrote this for IE8, which was the latest release of IE at the time, so it may not be as important to get this right as it once was.

Comment: Also potentially worth looking at this [implementation by Andrew Hedges](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/levenshtein/), code [here](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/levenshtein/levenshtein.js). I added it to [revision 17 in the jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/levenshtein-distance/17). On Chrome 31 it practically tied with Westgate and Stoianovici, would be interesting to see how it performs on other browsers

Comment: Someone may also want to digest this algorithm and see if it makes a difference -> http://blog.faroo.com/2012/06/07/improved-edit-distance-based-spelling-correction/

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, a little bug in the code though - in the damerau transposition we should have `i > 2 && j > 2` rather than `i > 1 && j > 1` - otherwise it may throw an exception.

Comment: Here's a different algorithm that may provide a performance increase - I havent though - tried it http://siderite.blogspot.com/2014/11/super-fast-and-accurate-string-distance.html

Comment: Unless I've implemented it wrong, there may be a bug with the Damerau transposition: This code seems to produce the result of 5 for ("84631","7345"), when the correct result is 4 (substitute 8 with 7, transpose 3 & 4, delete 6, substitute 1 with 5).

Comment: @Isaac look at the comment above which may help.

Comment: > `if (i == j && d[i][j] > 4) return n;`
What is this line supposed to do? It cheks if any diagonal (except `d[0][0]`) is greater than 4, but no such value exists before the loop (only the first row and col has any), and when d is mutated inside the loop, it is only the *current* cell `d[i][j]`, and only *below* this line. I see no case where the cell already has a value at that point?

Answer (score 13):

I came to this solution:

```
var levenshtein = (function() {
        var row2 = [];
        return function(s1, s2) {
            if (s1 === s2) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                var s1_len = s1.length, s2_len = s2.length;
                if (s1_len && s2_len) {
                    var i1 = 0, i2 = 0, a, b, c, c2, row = row2;
                    while (i1 < s1_len)
                        row[i1] = ++i1;
                    while (i2 < s2_len) {
                        c2 = s2.charCodeAt(i2);
                        a = i2;
                        ++i2;
                        b = i2;
                        for (i1 = 0; i1 < s1_len; ++i1) {
                            c = a + (s1.charCodeAt(i1) === c2 ? 0 : 1);
                            a = row[i1];
                            b = b < a ? (b < c ? b + 1 : c) : (a < c ? a + 1 : c);
                            row[i1] = b;
                        }
                    }
                    return b;
                } else {
                    return s1_len + s2_len;
                }
            }
        };
})();
```

See also http://jsperf.com/levenshtein-distance/12

Most speed was gained by eliminating some array usages.

Answer (score 6):

Updated: http://jsperf.com/levenshtein-distance/5

The new Revision annihilates all other benchmarks. I was specifically chasing Chromium/Firefox performance as I don't have an IE8/9/10 test environment, but the optimisations made should apply in general to most browsers.

**Levenshtein Distance**

The matrix to perform Levenshtein Distance can be reused again and again. This was an obvious target for optimisation (but be careful, this now imposes a limit on string length (unless you were to resize the matrix dynamically)).

The only option for optimisation not pursued in jsPerf Revision 5 is memoisation. Depending on your use of Levenshtein Distance, this could help drastically but was omitted due to its implementation specific nature.

```
// Cache the matrix. Note this implementation is limited to
// strings of 64 char or less. This could be altered to update
// dynamically, or a larger value could be used.
var matrix = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    matrix[i] = [i];
    matrix[i].length = 64;
}
for (var i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    matrix[0][i] = i;
}

// Functional implementation of Levenshtein Distance.
String.levenshteinDistance = function(__this, that, limit) {
    var thisLength = __this.length, thatLength = that.length;

    if (Math.abs(thisLength - thatLength) > (limit || 32)) return limit || 32;
    if (thisLength === 0) return thatLength;
    if (thatLength === 0) return thisLength;

    // Calculate matrix.
    var this_i, that_j, cost, min, t;
    for (i = 1; i <= thisLength; ++i) {
        this_i = __this[i-1];

        for (j = 1; j <= thatLength; ++j) {
            // Check the jagged ld total so far
            if (i === j && matrix[i][j] > 4) return thisLength;

            that_j = that[j-1];
            cost = (this_i === that_j) ? 0 : 1;  // Chars already match, no ++op to count.
            // Calculate the minimum (much faster than Math.min(...)).
            min    = matrix[i - 1][j    ] + 1;                      // Deletion.
            if ((t = matrix[i    ][j - 1] + 1   ) < min) min = t;   // Insertion.
            if ((t = matrix[i - 1][j - 1] + cost) < min) min = t;   // Substitution.

            matrix[i][j] = min; // Update matrix.
        }
    }

    return matrix[thisLength][thatLength];
};
```

**Damerau-Levenshtein Distance**

jsperf.com/damerau-levenshtein-distance

Damerau-Levenshtein Distance is a small modification to Levenshtein Distance to include transpositions. There is very little to optimise.

```
// Damerau transposition.
if (i > 1 && j > 1 && this_i === that[j-2] && this[i-2] === that_j
&& (t = matrix[i-2][j-2]+cost) < matrix[i][j]) matrix[i][j] = t;
```

**Sorting Algorithm**

The second part of this answer is to choose an appropriate sort function. I will upload optimised sort functions to http://jsperf.com/sort soon.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for your post! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Comment: Hi! Sorry, my mistake... I assumed stackoverflow was going to post my message under "anonymous" or "guest"... I see it has created a pseudo account... guess I'll register fully.

Comment: Hi, the prototype methods you include are bound to be slower so I cannot see their relevance in these tests.

Answer (score 4):

I implemented a very performant implementation of levenshtein distance calculation if you still need this.

```
function levenshtein(s, t) {
    if (s === t) {
        return 0;
    }
    var n = s.length, m = t.length;
    if (n === 0 || m === 0) {
        return n + m;
    }
    var x = 0, y, a, b, c, d, g, h, k;
    var p = new Array(n);
    for (y = 0; y < n;) {
        p[y] = ++y;
    }

    for (; (x + 3) < m; x += 4) {
        var e1 = t.charCodeAt(x);
        var e2 = t.charCodeAt(x + 1);
        var e3 = t.charCodeAt(x + 2);
        var e4 = t.charCodeAt(x + 3);
        c = x;
        b = x + 1;
        d = x + 2;
        g = x + 3;
        h = x + 4;
        for (y = 0; y < n; y++) {
            k = s.charCodeAt(y);
            a = p[y];
            if (a < c || b < c) {
                c = (a > b ? b + 1 : a + 1);
            }
            else {
                if (e1 !== k) {
                    c++;
                }
            }

            if (c < b || d < b) {
                b = (c > d ? d + 1 : c + 1);
            }
            else {
                if (e2 !== k) {
                    b++;
                }
            }

            if (b < d || g < d) {
                d = (b > g ? g + 1 : b + 1);
            }
            else {
                if (e3 !== k) {
                    d++;
                }
            }

            if (d < g || h < g) {
                g = (d > h ? h + 1 : d + 1);
            }
            else {
                if (e4 !== k) {
                    g++;
                }
            }
            p[y] = h = g;
            g = d;
            d = b;
            b = c;
            c = a;
        }
    }

    for (; x < m;) {
        var e = t.charCodeAt(x);
        c = x;
        d = ++x;
        for (y = 0; y < n; y++) {
            a = p[y];
            if (a < c || d < c) {
                d = (a > d ? d + 1 : a + 1);
            }
            else {
                if (e !== s.charCodeAt(y)) {
                    d = c + 1;
                }
                else {
                    d = c;
                }
            }
            p[y] = d;
            c = a;
        }
        h = d;
    }

    return h;
}
```

It was my answer to a similar SO question
[Fastest general purpose Levenshtein Javascript implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516942/fastest-general-purpose-levenshtein-javascript-implementation/35279162#35279162)

**Update**

A improved version of the above is now on github/npm see
https://github.com/gustf/js-levenshtein

Comment: Please check out [Take a tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Your answer is in another castle: When is an answer not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370)

Comment: @Drew Thanks, it was a bit unclear that the link was to another similar SO question. I changed it a bit. All good?

Comment: One way to think of it is, if your website link is not there, is that an answer. For 27, it is over 400 lines of code. So not sure what much to say. Not too easy to plop that in here.

Comment: Ok, I get your point. Added the implementation also now and also made a few other improvements. Thanks for taking the time to review my answer, I am still learning the SO way.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious way of doing this is to map each string to a (distance, string) pair, then sort this list, then drop the distances again. This way you ensure the levenstein distance only has to be computed once. Maybe merge duplicates first, too.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely suggest using a better Levenshtein method like the one in @James Westgate's answer.

That said, DOM manipulations are often a great expense. You can certainly improve your jQuery usage.

Your loops are rather small in the example above, but concatenating the generated html for each `oneResult` into a single string and doing one `append` at the end of the loop will be much more efficient.

Your selectors are slow. `$('.oneResult')` will search **all** elements in the DOM and test their `className` in older IE browsers. You may want to consider something like `atRes.find('.oneResult')` to scope the search.

In the case of adding the `click` handlers, we may want to do one better avoid setting handlers on every `keyup`. You could leverage event delegation by setting a single handler on `atRest` for all results in the same block you are setting the `keyup` handler:

```
atRest.on('click', '.oneResult', function(){
  window.location.href = 'http://hashtag.ly/' + $(this).html();
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/on/ for more info.

Comment: I believe that the question asked about Levenstein, however your answer was about  Jquery. Please consider revising your response into a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote an new revision: http://jsperf.com/levenshtein-algorithms/16

```
function levenshtein(a, b) {
  if (a === b) return 0;

  var aLen = a.length;
  var bLen = b.length;

  if (0 === aLen) return bLen;
  if (0 === bLen) return aLen;

  var len = aLen + 1;
  var v0 = new Array(len);
  var v1 = new Array(len);

  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  var c2, min, tmp;

  while (i < len) v0[i] = i++;

  while (j < bLen) {
    c2 = b.charAt(j++);
    v1[0] = j;
    i = 0;

    while (i < aLen) {
      min = v0[i] - (a.charAt(i) === c2 ? 1 : 0);
      if (v1[i] < min) min = v1[i];
      if (v0[++i] < min) min = v0[i];
      v1[i] = min + 1;
    }

    tmp = v0;
    v0 = v1;
    v1 = tmp;
  }
  return v0[aLen];
}
```

This revision is faster than the other ones. Works even on IE =)

Comment: Well, I removed the `-1`. Click the link and see, @axrwkr. Still, it should be at least mentioned here...

Comment: If the link dies, so does any value this answer has.  The code should be here, I reckon.