# Fastest general purpose Levenshtein Javascript implementation

Tags: javascript, levenshtein-distance

I am looking for a good general purpose Levenshtein implementation in Javascript. It must be fast and be useful for short and long strings. It should also be used many times (hence the caching). The most important thing is that it calculates a plain simple Levenshtein distance. I came up with this:

```
var levenshtein = (function() {
    var row2 = [];
    return function(s1, s2) {
        if (s1 === s2) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            var s1_len = s1.length, s2_len = s2.length;
            if (s1_len && s2_len) {
                var i1 = 0, i2 = 0, a, b, c, c2, row = row2;
                while (i1 < s1_len)
                    row[i1] = ++i1;
                while (i2 < s2_len) {
                    c2 = s2.charCodeAt(i2);
                    a = i2;
                    ++i2;
                    b = i2;
                    for (i1 = 0; i1 < s1_len; ++i1) {
                        c = a + (s1.charCodeAt(i1) === c2 ? 0 : 1);
                        a = row[i1];
                        b = b < a ? (b < c ? b + 1 : c) : (a < c ? a + 1 : c);
                        row[i1] = b;
                    }
                }
                return b;
            } else {
                return s1_len + s2_len;
            }
        }
    };
})();
```

Now I have two questions:

Can this be faster? I know by writing out the first iteration of each loop one can gain about 20%.

Is this code well written to serve as general purpose code, to be used in a library for instance?

Comment: Also review this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919065/sort-an-array-by-the-levenshtein-distance-with-best-performance-in-javascript/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We had a competition for fun at work about making the fastest levenshtein implementation and I came up with a faster one. First of all, I must say that it was not easy to beat your solution which was the fastest to find "out there". :)

This is tested with node.js and it my benchmarks results indicates that this implementation is ~15% faster on small texts (random words size 2-10 characters) and over twice as fast on longer texts (with lengths 30+ containing random characters)

Note: I removed array caching of all implementations

```
function levenshtein(s, t) {
    if (s === t) {
        return 0;
    }
    var n = s.length, m = t.length;
    if (n === 0 || m === 0) {
        return n + m;
    }
    var x = 0, y, a, b, c, d, g, h, k;
    var p = new Array(n);
    for (y = 0; y < n;) {
        p[y] = ++y;
    }

    for (; (x + 3) < m; x += 4) {
        var e1 = t.charCodeAt(x);
        var e2 = t.charCodeAt(x + 1);
        var e3 = t.charCodeAt(x + 2);
        var e4 = t.charCodeAt(x + 3);
        c = x;
        b = x + 1;
        d = x + 2;
        g = x + 3;
        h = x + 4;
        for (y = 0; y < n; y++) {
            k = s.charCodeAt(y);
            a = p[y];
            if (a < c || b < c) {
                c = (a > b ? b + 1 : a + 1);
            }
            else {
                if (e1 !== k) {
                    c++;
                }
            }

            if (c < b || d < b) {
                b = (c > d ? d + 1 : c + 1);
            }
            else {
                if (e2 !== k) {
                    b++;
                }
            }

            if (b < d || g < d) {
                d = (b > g ? g + 1 : b + 1);
            }
            else {
                if (e3 !== k) {
                    d++;
                }
            }

            if (d < g || h < g) {
                g = (d > h ? h + 1 : d + 1);
            }
            else {
                if (e4 !== k) {
                    g++;
                }
            }
            p[y] = h = g;
            g = d;
            d = b;
            b = c;
            c = a;
        }
    }

    for (; x < m;) {
        var e = t.charCodeAt(x);
        c = x;
        d = ++x;
        for (y = 0; y < n; y++) {
            a = p[y];
            if (a < c || d < c) {
                d = (a > d ? d + 1 : a + 1);
            }
            else {
                if (e !== s.charCodeAt(y)) {
                    d = c + 1;
                }
                else {
                    d = c;
                }
            }
            p[y] = d;
            c = a;
        }
        h = d;
    }

    return h;
}
```

On longer texts it will get almost up to 3 times the speed of your implementation if it initially cache the inner loop's `s.charCodeAt(y)` in an `Uint32Array`. Longer texts also seemed to benefit from using a `Uint16Array` as a the distance cost array. Here is the code for that solution

```
function levenshtein(s, t) {
    if (s === t) {
        return 0;
    }
    var n = s.length, m = t.length;
    if (n === 0 || m === 0) {
        return n + m;
    }
    var x = 0, y, a, b, c, d, g, h;
    var p = new Uint16Array(n);
    var u = new Uint32Array(n);
    for (y = 0; y < n;) {
        u[y] = s.charCodeAt(y);
        p[y] = ++y;
    }

    for (; (x + 3) < m; x += 4) {
        var e1 = t.charCodeAt(x);
        var e2 = t.charCodeAt(x + 1);
        var e3 = t.charCodeAt(x + 2);
        var e4 = t.charCodeAt(x + 3);
        c = x;
        b = x + 1;
        d = x + 2;
        g = x + 3;
        h = x + 4;
        for (y = 0; y < n; y++) {
            a = p[y];
            if (a < c || b < c) {
                c = (a > b ? b + 1 : a + 1);
            }
            else {
                if (e1 !== u[y]) {
                    c++;
                }
            }

            if (c < b || d < b) {
                b = (c > d ? d + 1 : c + 1);
            }
            else {
                if (e2 !== u[y]) {
                    b++;
                }
            }

            if (b < d || g < d) {
                d = (b > g ? g + 1 : b + 1);
            }
            else {
                if (e3 !== u[y]) {
                    d++;
                }
            }

            if (d < g || h < g) {
                g = (d > h ? h + 1 : d + 1);
            }
            else {
                if (e4 !== u[y]) {
                    g++;
                }
            }
            p[y] = h = g;
            g = d;
            d = b;
            b = c;
            c = a;
        }
    }

    for (; x < m;) {
        var e = t.charCodeAt(x);
        c = x;
        d = ++x;
        for (y = 0; y < n; y++) {
            a = p[y];
            if (a < c || d < c) {
                d = (a > d ? d + 1 : a + 1);
            }
            else {
                if (e !== u[y]) {
                    d = c + 1;
                }
                else {
                    d = c;
                }
            }
            p[y] = d;
            c = a;
        }
        h = d;
    }

    return h;
}
```

All benchmark results is from my tests and test-data might be different with your test-data.

The main 2 difference in this solution than to yours (and some other fast ones) I think is

- Not always do compare of the characters in the inner loop if not necessary.
- Sort of "Loop unrolling" in the outer loop doing 4 rows at a time in the levenshtein "matrix". This was a major performance win.

http://jsperf.com/levenshtein-distance/24

I will put this solution on github when I find the time :)

**Update**:
Finally, I put the solution on github
https://github.com/gustf/js-levenshtein. Its a bit modified/optimized but it is the same base algorithm.

Comment: Got it even 3-4% percent faster on longer texts by changing to a Uint16Array as the "charCode"-cache. Should be ok as String.charCodeAt always returns an int less than 65536.

Comment: Another 6-7% faster with longer texts (100+) by using a variable for `u[y]` in the inner loop, did not expect that. Thought the compiler would optimize that for me.

Comment: Finally a reaction! You use techniques I did not have available at the time. I had to stick to ES5. But your code is also different in other parts. Interesting!

Comment: True about ES6, but in my benchmarks I modified your solution to use `new Array(n)` :) Would be very interesting to hear if you are getting improved performance in your use case also.

Comment: Just clarifying.  So this function is just looking for two strings like `var s = "some long or short string";` and `var t = "a second string to which one would compare";`.  Is that correct?  It will then output those results somewhere else, where the function was called, like `"var levenshteinDistance = levenshtein(s, t);`.