# Calculate added characters between 2 strings (even when others are removed)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, algorithm, calculation

I have an initial string which will be changed and I want to know how many new characters were added (even when others are removed).

For exemple:

```
Initial string ==> "I love Programming so much"
Changed string ==> "I used to love programming"


Changes:


"used to " 8 chars added
" so much" 8 chars deleted
```

The result I want is the number of added chars which is 8.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Have you tried comparing the length of the string before and after adding/removing characters?

Comment: Folks, that would give them the value `0`. They want `8` (the number added, even though 8 were also removed).

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes both strings have 26 chars so the result will be 0 which is wrong

Comment: Yes @T.J.Crowder exactly!

Comment: You might want to fix the strings in the question, one has `P` the other has `p`. Which also brings us to: What about if a character is **changed**? Does that count as an addition?

Comment: "Diffing" text is a complicated area. There should be libraries you can find that would help you with this.

Comment: Thank you @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 7):

The number of characters you have to change to get from one string to another is called the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), sounds like that might be what you want.
You can find some JS implementations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516942/fastest-general-purpose-levenshtein-javascript-implementation/35279162).

Comment: Thank you so much @Jotha this what i was looking for!

Comment: After testing this solution it appeared that it's not what I needed , but I feel like I'm getting closer to find the right solution