# Finding the Indices of the Differences using Damerau–Levenshtein Method

Tags: javascript, levenshtein-distance

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11958496/379650 provides a very good function for calculating the Damerau–Levenshtein distance, however, I would like to be able to find the index of each of the differences given in terms of either the first or second string.

I am open to some other method better than Damerau–Levenshtein distance (if there is one), but it seemed like the most logical choice.

Example:

```
//Indices given in terms of the first string
ld('abc','abc');//[] no mistakes
ld('abc','abd');//[2]
ld('abc','aad');//[1,2]
ld('abc','ac');//[1]
```

Comment: Don't quite understand, can you post an example of input and output?

Comment: I see, no idea, haven't used that script...