# javascript: return a string similarity score between two strings

Tags: javascript, string

Is there a library or a certain technique to measure similarity between two strings in Javascript? Would levensctein distance be relevant use here?

for example

```
some/dir/index[3]/out
some/dir/index[4]/out
```

should return a decimal score indicating how close the strings are.

vs

```
some/dir/index[3]/out
some/dir/index[3]/out/more/dir
```

should represent a much further apart in similarity.

Comment: I do not know of any library that exists within Javascript for this, but implementing Levenshtein distance would be the most algorithmic approach to it (and a good coding exercise). Here is another StackOverflow question that answers this to some extent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919065/sort-an-array-by-the-levenshtein-distance-with-best-performance-in-javascript. There is code in there, which I would advise you use after you've made your own attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is reference to a library called [jsdifflib](https://github.com/cemerick/jsdifflib).

[Here](http://cemerick.github.io/jsdifflib/demo.html) is a demo which gives this.

Comment: Hmmm, this library gives you a line by line comparison, but does it work down to the characters?

Comment: @Zhouster if it doesn't worth, let me know, I'll delete my ans.

Comment: Oh, I only quickly perused the documentation and the demo. It seems to only indicate line-by-line difference. However, I do think it's an interesting resource.