# How to use javascript to filter a large list by html attribute value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a reference guide for a mixture of many html icons. I have the following html code:

```
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search Icons">
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit!">
<input id="cancel" type="button" value="Cancel">
<div id="icon-list">
    <li>
        <div class="icon icon-name"></div>
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="name">
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="icon icon-name2"></div>
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="name2">
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="icon icon-name3"></div>
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="name3">
    </li>
    <!-- repeated 100 or more times -->
</div>
```

I'd like to be able to filter out the icons(<li>) based on the value attribute of the input inside it, preferably using fuzzy search. Is there a library or some code that can do this for me?

**EDIT:**
I'd like to know mainly how to implement the search from the value of the `value` attribute, not how to implement the fuzzy search. Example:

Comment: you want a fuzzy matching with the value? how fuzzy? regex-fuzzy? or is there another fuzzier fuzzy?

Comment: Not that fuzzy. Just fuzzy enough so that misspellings will still work. Maybe only 1 or 2 letters are wrong? for example, I want `safe` to still show if the user searches for `sfae`

Comment: Levenshtein might be what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919065/sort-an-array-by-the-levenshtein-distance-with-best-performance-in-javascript

Comment: @le_m the problem is I don't know how to get the array of what to search.

Comment: Best solution would be to have a hashmap/array with all your icon/names as well as an input element. As soon as you type, the result list is build by searching through the hashmap/array according to the linked question. You can then easily generate a html structure from the results as you did above.

Comment: @le_m I didn't make the icons. I generated the icon font from a website and its a combination of  different icons from different icon sets. So I can't really put all the names into a array. Is there some code that will allow me to illiterate through all the children of the div and then sort it from there?

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is off-topic. The rest of the question is okay, but you should show what you've attempted so far and where you're getting stuck. Take a look at [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you're interested in is filtering the `li`s based on the value in the input, that can be done many, many ways. I threw something together with jQuery, but anything with a view layer, like React or Angular, could manage. Fuzzy searches aren't terribly well defined, but the [Fuse.js](https://github.com/krisk/Fuse) does some kind of fuzzy search. I plugged it in.

For about a 100, you could probably get away with a similar implementation like below (there's a lot of efficiency that can be picked up with all the jQuery calls).

```js
var liElements = $.makeArray($('#icon-list li').map(function(idx, elm) {
  var jElm = $(elm);
  var value = jElm.find('input').attr('value');
  return {
    jElm, value
  };
}));
var fuse = new Fuse(liElements, {
  keys: ["value"],
  threshold: 0.2
});

var search = $('#search');
var filter = function() {
  var target = search.val().trim();
  if (target.length < 1) {
    liElements.forEach(function(obj) {
      obj.jElm.show();
    });
    return;
  }
  var results = fuse.search(target);

  liElements.forEach(function(obj) {
    obj.jElm.hide();
  });
  results.forEach(function(obj) {
    obj.jElm.show();
  });
};


search.keyup(filter);
$('#submit').click(filter);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fuse.js/2.2.0/fuse.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search Icons">
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit!">
<input id="cancel" type="button" value="Cancel">
<div id="icon-list">
  <li>
    <div class="icon icon-name"></div>
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="teal">
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="icon icon-name2"></div>
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="mittens">
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="icon icon-name3"></div>
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="mittons">
  </li>
  <!-- repeated 100 or more times -->
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe replace the shorthand property names object initialiser with the regular long form, for browser compatibility.

Comment: Library recommendations are off-topic and you don't need jQuery. However, +1 for clearly demonstrating the mechanics of a straightforward solution.

Comment: @FIzzyTea Agreed, you certainly don't need jQuery, but it was late and it saved me a couple of lines. And same goes for the shorthand init. jQuery or not, this design is pretty rough on the DOM and could (should, for production) be improved quite a bit. Purely a conceptual demo.

Comment: Agreed, you shouldn't be storing data in the DOM at all.