# is there a way to see what is most closely related to a given string in an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I mean like even if you misspell Pikachi it auto corrects to Pikachu because its the most closely related

For example

```js
let array = ["Pikachu","Rawrr","Squirtle]
let string = "Pikachi"
function(string) // will return "Pikachu"
```

In my case, I gave the string Pikachi and it was most related to Pikachu and it does not match any string in the array so it chose that. How can I do this in javascript?

Comment: Consider factoring in the concept of edit distance perhaps? The one with minimum edit distance matches most closely

Comment: search `levenshtein javascript`, quite a few packages out there

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone 
do you think using a package would be the fastest option?

Comment: define fastest? writing it yourself, running or installing? there is other examples/snippets you could use https://gist.github.com/andrei-m/982927

Comment: Ill try to implement a test using it right now

Comment: I jumped the gun on duping it was a PHP one, but here is one in js: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919065/sort-an-array-by-the-levenshtein-distance-with-best-performance-in-javascript/11958496

Comment: using linked dupes function, it doesn't show an example to sort, so here is one: https://playcode.io/674126/ - could answer but think it's bad form