# two sets of strings, how to compare the percentage they are the same?

Tags: javascript

I have a set of strings that look like this,

```
{0:{question:"1f31f", answer:"1f31a"},1:{question:"1f32f", answer:"1fada"}}
```

I'm trying to use Javascript to show the percentage similarity between these strong strings - wondering if there's a simple way to do this?

Based on the index of the string, how many are correctly positioned.

Comment: depends of your definition of "similarity"

Comment: good point. I suppose, based on the index of the string, how many are correct positioned.

Comment: Typically the Levenstein algorithm is used to quantify similarities between string. Do a search on Google and you will find dozens of implementations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort an array by the "Levenshtein Distance" with best performance in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919065/sort-an-array-by-the-levenshtein-distance-with-best-performance-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the strings are always of the same length, consider calculating their [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance). If they are not always of the same length, look into the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Comment: always same length

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't know how complex you want your answer to be and others already provided some great methods, I figured I just submit the most simple, plain answer since sometimes that is all you need. Just comparing how many indices are the same:

```js
let s1 = "1f31f";
let s2 = "1f31a"
let s3 = "1fada";

compare(s1, s2);
compare(s1, s3);

function compare(s1, s2) {
  let correct = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
    if (s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(i)) {
      correct += 1;
    }
  }

  console.log(((correct / s1.length) * 100) + "%");
}
```